# Issue in complicated join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 4 tables

tbLicenceTypesX (2 Fields)

- LicenceTypes
- LicenceTypesX

tbLicenceTypesX (Contains data like)

- 1 - Medical Licence
- 2 - Property
- 3 - Casualty
- 4 - Trainning Licence

tbProduct (3 feilds)

- Product
- ProductX
- CompanyId (F.K)
- LicenceTypes(F.K)

tbProduct (Contains data like)

- 1 - T.V - 10 -  2
- 2 - A.C - 30 -  3
- 3 - Mobiles - 40 -4

tbLicence (3 feilds)

- Licence
- LicenceTypesNames
- AgentId

tbLicence (Contains data like)

- 1 - Property, Casualty - 23
- 2 - Trainning Licence, Casualty - 34

Now I have to Fetch Product and ProductX from tbProduct whose LicenceTypes matches with Agent's Licence in tbLicence in a Company.

For e.g: I have to fetch T.V Whose Licence Types is 2("Property") and Company Id is 10 which should be assigned to Agent where Agent Id is 23  and Whose LicenceTypesNames should also contains "Property"

I want to fetch something like

```
        @CompanyId int, 
        @AgentId int
        As
        SELECT p.ProductX,p.Product
        from tbProduct p
        inner join tbLicence l on p.LicenceTypes = l.LicenceTypesNames<its corresponding Id>
        inner  join tbProduct c on c.Product =p.Product 
        where
        c.CompanyId=@CompanyId
        and l.AgentId=@AgentId
```

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XML` and `CROSS APPLY` to Split the `comma` separated values and `JOIN` with `tbProduct`. The `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` functions are used to trim the comma separated values if they have excessive empty space.  The below code gives you the desired output.

```
DECLARE @CompanyId int = 30, @AgentId int = 23

 ;WITH CTE AS
 ( 
    SELECT AgentId, TCT.LicenceTypes FROM
    (
        SELECT AgentId, LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.XMLData.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)'))) LicenceTypesNames FROM
        (
            SELECT AgentID, Cast ('<M>' + REPLACE(LicenceTypesNames, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data
            FROM   tbLicence 
        ) AS XMLData
            CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(XMLData) 
    )
    AS LTN 
    JOIN tbLicenceTypesX TCT  ON LTN.LicenceTypesNames = tct.LicenceTypesX
)

SELECT  p.ProductX,p.Product 
FROM tbProduct P
JOIN CTE c on p.LicenceTypes = c.LicenceTypes
WHERE CompanyId = @CompanyId
AND AgentId = @AgentId
```

[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2cf64/2)